# Visual Studio Server Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am using `visual studio 2008` and `SQl Server 2008.`
I recently formatted my machine so i had to install `Visual Studio 2008` again.
I am trying to use `Linq To Sql` for getting data from backend.
However when i add .dbml class and try to drag and drop tables ... I am unabel to do it.The server explorer just doesnot do anything....I just keep clicking the server explorer link and it doesnot show tables for me.
What could be the issue.Any ideas.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. click http://floomby.ru/content/r0t1b16RDU
2. choose Microsoft SQL Server
3. choose Server and DataBase
4. drag and drop tables

Comment: ,,,, i did not get your solution ,,, how is that going to help me.